# Perl inotify2 triggers twice for each file modification

Tags: linux, perl, inotify

I am writing a Perl script which monitors a file for changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Linux::Inotify2;

my $inotify = new Linux::Inotify2 or die $!;
my $filename = "/tmp/foo";
my $counter = 0;

$inotify->watch (
    $filename,
    IN_MODIFY,
    sub {
        ++$counter;
        print "changed: $counter\n";
    }
) or die $!;

1 while $inotify->poll;
```

This handler is called twice (incrementing $counter twice) each time /tmp/foo changes if I test it like this:

```
echo abc > /tmp/foo
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use `>>` as @Lajos Veres suggested, or watch on `CLOSE_WRITE` event (that is [IN_CLOSE_WRITE](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.22/Inotify2.pm#The_Linux::Inotify2_Class) for `Linux::Inotify2` module),

```
echo > /tmp/foo
```

---

```
inotifywait -m /tmp/foo
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/tmp/foo MODIFY
/tmp/foo OPEN
/tmp/foo MODIFY
/tmp/foo CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
```

Comment: `Bareword "CLOSE_WRITE" not allowed while "strict subs"` although IN_MODIFY runs without complaint. What gives?

Comment: try with IN_CLOSE_WRITE

Answer (score 5):

The > truncates first the file (I think it is a modification itself also). Try with >>.